# how to read data.sqlite file in Python?

Tags: python, sql

I have one data.sqllite file!

can anyone tell me what is the way to read that file in Python??

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
```

Comment: i want to see whole the  data in python , how to do that, once i read it
because after that i want to run query!

Comment: `for row in conn.execute('SELECT * FROM table'):
        print row`